# How to process the FinQA data for machine learning

Tags: python-3.x, bert-language-model

I want to understand the FinQA dataset which is a dataset for Q&A task for Kaggle, the structure of this file is little too complex, just wanted to know if anyone of you have ever tried to process the file and use it to train a model like BERT.

```
# Load the data
with open('./FinQA-main/dataset/dev.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
# Preprocess the data
processed_data = []
for item in data[:5]:
    question = item.get('pre_text')  # replace 'Question' with the actual key if different
    answer = item.get('post_text')  # replace 'Answer' with the actual key if different
    print(question)
    print(answer)
    #processed_data.append(question + ' ' + answer)
```

I am so far trying to understand the dataset, i see i has list of values in pre_text and post_text, i am trying to convert it in a csv file with pre_text as "input"  and post_text as "target"  variables and then train a model like bert . I actually want to fine tune a LLM model like gpt3 using this dataset- this is a financial question-answering dataset.